# Pythonのset(集合)の表示順序について

Tags: python, python3

最近Pythonを学び始めた者です。初歩的なことかも知れませんが、調べても望むような答えが見つかりませんでしたので質問させていただければと思います。

set(集合)について、公式ドキュメントにもあるように｢重複する要素をもたない、順序づけられていない要素の集まり｣と認識していました。

```
s = set()
s.add("a")
s.add("b")
s.add("c")
print(s) # {'c', 'a', 'b'}や{'a', 'c', 'b'}など
```

実際、上記のようにprintした際の要素の表示順はランダムになるものだと思っていたのですが、

```
s = set()
s.add(1)
s.add(2)
s.add(3)
print(s) # {1, 2, 3}
```

このコードでは常に昇順で表示されます。

この理由はなんでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***この理由はなんでしょうか。***

「たまたま」です。

まず、ひとつ確認しておかなくてはいけないのは「順序づけられていない」と言うのと「printした際の要素の表示順はランダムになる」と言うのとは別だと言うことです。

Pythonがある要素を`set`に保持する場合、その内部的な順序は「簡単に予測出来ない何らかの方法」で決まります。ランダムに決めるかどうかは「順序づけられていない」と言う言葉には含まれていません。

したがって、特定の要素(1,2,3)を`set`に保持した後、printした際の表示順が「たまたま昇順」になることはいくらでもあり得ます。「何らかの方法」が非決定性の乱数かなんかに基づく挙動を示すなんて保証もありませんから、「たまたま」(その要素の組み合わせの場合には)「常に昇順で表示」されるように見えることもあるかもしれません。

こちらは「python set order」で出てきた記事の例:

```
s = set()
s.add(1)
s.add(2)
s.add(20)
s.add(6)
s.add(100)
print(s) # ->{1, 2, 100, 6, 20}
```

私が試したところ、上の例は昇順でも要素の追加順でもない順番で表示されました。別のバージョンの処理系であれば、別の順番になるかもしれません。

Comment: 早速のご回答ありがとうございます。なんとなくですがわかったような気がしました。
｢Pythonが、ある"簡単に予測出来ない何らかの方法"で、要素の内部的な順番を決めており、それをprintしてみたら、たまたま昇順になった。その"なんらかの方法"は、誰にも分からないもの(開発者ならわかるかも知れない?)。｣という認識で合っていますか?

挙げて頂いた例の他にもいろんな数で試したところ、確かに組み合わせによって昇順になったりならなかったりしました。 ありがとうございます。

Comment: @code320 さん、「誰にも分からないもの(開発者ならわかるかも知れない?)」と言うのは微妙に違いますね。Pythonの`set`型は「ハッシュテーブル」に基づく実装になっています。(辞書型なんかの実装にも使われているアルゴリズム/データ構造です。)要素を付け加えるためには「要素のハッシュ値を計算する」「ハッシュ値から内部の記憶領域の場所を計算する」「その場所が空いていればそこに格納する」(printなんかの際にはおそらく)「内部の記憶領域から埋まっている値を順番に取り出す」と言うことをやっているはずです。それぞれのステップにアルゴリズムやパラメータでバリエーションがあるものの、逆に言えばそれらがわかれば完全に予測できます(Pythonでは乱数ベースの実装はしていないようです)。もっとも、いろんなケースできちんと予測するのは大変なんで、開発者でも難しいですが。興味がおありなら「ハッシュテーブル」で検索してみれば、良記事も見つかると思います。

Comment: そのあたりも勉強してみようと思います。ご丁寧にありがとうございました!